# gzip i/o error while wrinting to NAS

Tags: mount, tar, nas, gzip

I have a backup script that creates a backup archive onto a mounted NAS drive:

```
tar zcf /mnt/nas_drive/backup.tgz .??* *
```

About 50% of the time, the process fails with the following error message:

```
gzip: write error: Input/output error
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

If I read this correctly, gzip (which is a subprocess of the tar) is unable to **write** on the destination (the NAS). Hence the failure.

Is there a way I can get more details on what's causing the error (i.e. increase verbosity)?

Typically, it could get triggered by insufficient disk space (which is not the case), quotas (which I don't know about), broken pipes, ...

It would be really nice to be able to get more details.

Comment: @24601 unfortunately not...

Comment: When the error occurs does anything get logged to /var/log/syslog ?

Comment: Does anything get logged on the NAS?  On Ubuntu `sudo journalctl -b 0 /mnt/nas_drive`.